# atribute a value in static function php

Tags: php

I would reuse a variable `$spider_flag` inside static function to include in other static function. How to do that ?

TK

```
 public static function start() {

 $spider_flag = false;

          if (!empty($user_agent) || strpos ($user_agent, "Googlebot") > 0) {
            $user_agent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

            if (!empty($user_agent)) {
              foreach (file(Sites/Assets/spiders.txt') as $spider) {
                if (!empty($spider)) {
                  if (strpos($user_agent, $spider) !== false) {
                    $wo_full_name = $spider;
                    $spider_flag = true;

                    break;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

the other function

```
 public static function getResultSpiderFlag() {
      $spider_flag= ????
      return $spider_flag;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below class definition:

```
public static $spider_flag;
```

inside function

```
self::$spider_flag = 'something'
```

or

```
self::$spider_flag //for the value;
```

Comment: I replace all $spider_flag by self::$spider_flag and in getResultSpiderFlag I return just self::$spider_flag. Is it correct

Comment: yes that is the way to go, if you want a getter make the static var private, so it is not accesable outside of the class